# Prevent repeating expression in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this query  :

```
SELECT ..... ,( CAST(col1 AS MONEY) / CAST (col2 AS MONEY) ) as calc1 from mytable...
```

(returns 1000 rows)

Now I need to add *more columns* based on `calc1` expression ( e.g. `calc2 = calc1 * 4`)

I don't want to do this :

```
SELECT (CAST(col1 AS MONEY) / CAST(col2 AS MONEY)) AS calc1,    --same 
       (CAST(col1 AS MONEY) / CAST(col2 AS MONEY)) * 4 AS calc2,    -- dragged calc1 
       ((CAST(col1 AS MONEY) / CAST(col2 AS MONEY)) * 4) * 50 AS calc2, -- dragged calc2 
       (((CAST(col1 AS MONEY) / CAST(col2 AS MONEY)) * 4) * 50) * 60 AS calc2 -- dragged calc3
```

visualization : the yellow part is repeating itself with added calculations...

[image]

what is the best way of doing this ?

Comment: Depending on what your `col1` and `col2` values are, it may turn out that `money` is a pretty poor datatype to choose: `select (((CAST(1 AS MONEY) / CAST(100000 AS MONEY)) * 4) * 50) * 60,(((CAST(1 AS decimal(20,4)) / CAST(100000 AS decimal(20,4))) * 4) * 50) * 60`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a common table expression (CTE):

```
;with calcCTE
AS
(
  SELECT (CAST(col1 AS MONEY) / CAST(col2 AS MONEY)) AS calc1
  FROM <table>
)
SELECT calc1,
       calc1 * 4,
       calc1 * 200,
       calc1 * 12000
FROM calcCTE
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly you don't want to repeat the equation each time you use it.  If so consider a view, either a permanet or in line one and reference the column in the select (or outer select if an inline view).

Comment: if calc3 based on calc2 based on calc1 I dont want to have 3 "one on top" select's...

Comment: the only options I can see is nested views or repeating the syntax in a single query.  E.g. calc2 would have the same text plus more as calc1.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is to define your equations as scalar functions and then you could do something like:

```
SELECT dbo.calc1(col1, col2) AS Calc1, dbo.calc3(col1, col2) AS Calc3
FROM transactions
```

and inside your function for Calc3 you could just return `SELECT calc2(col1, col2) * 50` which in return would just return `SELECT calc1(col1, col2) * 4`

This will work so long as your equations don't change.

You could even go further and define a multiplier variable so that you try and re-use the calculations as much as you can.